# event when component is mounted before render React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating an React Native App with tab and stack navigation. Is there any solution to handle  when its just navigated before render?

For example:

```
Chats.jsx
...
<Pressable
    onPress={() => props.navigate('Messages', { chatId: chat.id })}
                        ><Chats/>
                        </Pressable>
...
```

I click the button and jump to `MessagesScreen.jsx` screen.

```
MessagesScreen.jsx
...
//Some logic after navigation event. For example, I want to fetch data from a remote source and show at the screen.
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `focus` event, something like this:

```
function MessagesScreen({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // TODO
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <... />;
}
```

See [React Navigation lifecycle events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle#react-navigation-lifecycle-events) for details.